# Flex issue with safari

Tags: safari, bootstrap-4

I used Bs4 for my new template and I have issue with flex on safari 8.x. When I use col-lg-6, it dont wrap with screen width smaller than 992. Its not responsive. Please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: show your code please

Comment: .container>.row>.col-lg-6(x2)